# How to configure a subdirectory project in CMake in a way that find_package in another one is able to find it?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build the netCDF C++ library as a dependency to my project on Windows 10 using MSVC shipped with VS2017 (I think v141 but not sure). Since some of the dependencies I will mention below require CMake > 3.12 I am forced to use CMake that is not shipped with VS2017. The problem is that netCDF C++ requires the netCDF C library (I guess the former is a wrapper for the latter), which in terms depends on the HDF5 library.

All can be found on github as CMake projects:

- https://github.com/HDFGroup/hdf5
- https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c
- https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-cxx4

Currently my project's structure is as follows:

```
MAIN PROJECT
|
*--- CMakeLists.txt
|
*--- examples (CMake subproject)
|       |
|       *---CMakeLists.txt
|                 |
|                 *--- example1 (CMake subproject, uses my_library)
|                 |
|                 *--- example2 (CMake subproject, uses my_library)
|
*--- deps (CMake subproject)
|      |
|      *--- CMakeLists.txt
|      |
|      *--- jsoncpp (CMake subproject, git clone)
|      |
|      *--- ...
|      |
|      *--- hdf5 (CMake subproject, git clone)
|      |
|      *--- netcdf-c (CMake subproject, git clone)
|      |
|      *--- netcdf-cxx4 (CMake subproject, git clone)
|
*--- my_library (CMake subproject, my own library that uses deps)
|
*--- my_binary (CMake subproject, my own executable that uses my_library and deps)
```

Until I started tinkering with netCDF I didn't have any issues. My **deps** `CMakeLists.txt` look like this:

```
add_subdirectory(sqlite3)

set(JSONCPP_WITH_EXAMPLE OFF CACHE BOOL "Compile JsonCpp example")
set(JSONCPP_WITH_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "Compile and (for jsoncpp_check) run JsonCpp test executables")
set(JSONCPP_WITH_POST_BUILD_UNITTEST OFF CACHE BOOL "Automatically run unit-tests as a post build step")
set(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS ON CACHE BOOL "Build jsoncpp_lib as a static library.")
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build jsoncpp_lib as a shared library.")
add_subdirectory(jsoncpp)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build shared libraries")
set(BUILD_CURL_EXE OFF CACHE BOOL "Build curl EXE")
add_definitions("-DCURL_STATICLIB")
if(WIN32)
    set(ENABLE_UNICODE OFF CACHE BOOL "Set to ON to use the Unicode version of the Windows API functions")
endif()
add_subdirectory(curl)

add_subdirectory(hdf5)
add_subdirectory(netcdf-c)  # ISSUE with find_package and hdf5
add_subdirectory(netcdf-cxx4)
```

The `netcdf-c` subproject has the following lines, which cause a problem for me:

```
IF(MSVC)
      SET(SEARCH_PACKAGE_NAME ${HDF5_PACKAGE_NAME})
      FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5 NAMES ${SEARCH_PACKAGE_NAME} COMPONENTS C HL CONFIG REQUIRED ${NC_HDF5_LINK_TYPE})
ELSE(MSVC)
      FIND_PACKAGE(HDF5 COMPONENTS C HL REQUIRED)
ENDIF(MSVC)
```

From what I saw the same applies to `netcdf-cxx4` so solving this can hopefully be applied to it too.

I do not want to touch anything inside the respective dependenies' folders (I plan on adding those as `git submodules` later on). Is there a way to instruct the underlying sub-project (just like a did for e.g. JSON++) where to look without installing anything from the project one level up? Possibly a useful note here is that I also don't have any `install()` calls.

Comment: `find_package` is not intended to be used with `add_subdirectory`. Depending on the mode it either looks for a config file or a FindModule file. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html I suggest you get familiar with https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: Ah, I have forgotten about `ExternalProject`! Thanks a lot.