# CMake FetchContent fails with error "fatal: could not create work tree dir '': No such file or directory"

Tags: git, cmake, dependency-management

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73290340/how-to-configure-a-subdirectory-project-in-cmake-in-a-way-that-find-package-in-a) of mine I am trying to use `ExternalProject_Add()` to add all my external dependencies. Since some of these depend on each other and use `find_package()` I am actually using `FetchContent` (namely `FetchContent_Declare()` followed by `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` to actually make the external source tree available during configuration time).

All of my dependencies are external git repositories. One such example is [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git). So in my dependencies `subdirectory` I added the following:

```
find_package(Git REQUIRED)
if(Git_FOUND)
  message("Git found: ${GIT_EXECUTABLE}")
endif()

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(jsoncpp
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git
    GIT_TAG origin/master
    SUBBUILD_DIR "${DEPS_ARTIFACTS}/populate/jsoncpp/"
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/jsoncpp_external/"
    FIND_PACKAGE_ARGS NAMES jsoncpp
    # Following will be internally passed down to ExternalProject_Add (at least what
    # I understood from the documentation)
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DJSONCPP_WITH_EXAMPLE=OFF
        -DJSONCPP_WITH_TESTS=OFF
        -DJSON_WITH_POST_BUILD_UNITTEST=OFF
        -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
    TMP_DIR "${DEPS_ARTIFACTS}/tmp/jsoncpp/"
    STAMP_DIR "${DEPS_ARTIFACTS}/stamp/jsoncpp/"
    LOG_DIR "${DEPS_ARTIFACTS}/log/jsoncpp/"
    BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/jsoncpp_external/"
    DOWNLOAD_DIR "${DEPS_ARTIFACTS}/downloads/jsoncpp/"
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(jsoncpp)
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the shipped MSVC (v141 I think). Since some of the dependencies require CMake > 3.12 I am using my own installation of CMake.

The configuration step fails (if I remove the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` line I do get the solution, which I can load in Visual Studio but it fails with a similar git-related error message):

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 to target Windows 10.0.14393.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27048.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27048.0
...
Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe (found version "2.27.0.windows.1") 
Git found: C:/Program Files/Git/cmd/git.exe
Microsoft (R)-Build-Engine, Version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 für .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

  Creating directories for 'jsoncpp-populate'
  Building Custom Rule D:/USER/Projects/PROJECT/build/artifacts/populate/jsoncpp/CMakeLists.txt
  Performing download step (git clone) for 'jsoncpp-populate'
  fatal: could not create work tree dir '': No such file or directory
  fatal: could not create work tree dir '': No such file or directory
  fatal: could not create work tree dir '': No such file or directory
  -- Had to git clone more than once:
  CMake Error at D:/USER/Projects/PROJECT/build/artifacts/tmp/jsoncpp/jsoncpp-populate-gitclone.cmake:31 (message):
            3 times.
    Failed to clone repository:
    'https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git'
  
  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code 1 beendet. [D:\USER\Projects\PROJECT\build\artifacts\populate\jsoncpp\jsoncpp-populate.vcxproj]

CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:915 (message):
  Build step for jsoncpp failed: 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1006 (__FetchContent_directPopulate)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1047 (FetchContent_Populate)
  deps/CMakeLists.txt:92 (FetchContent_MakeAvailable)

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/USER/Projects/PROJECT/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I also have to mention that I am behind a proxy. Normally I am using Git Bash to clone and execute other git-related operations. However the error doesn't seem to have anything to do with that. Last but not least I do not have administrative privileges on the machine so it might be an access issue. Then again the `''` indicates an empty name, which (for obvious reasons) cannot work for creating a folder. Perhaps I am missing an argument?

---

**NOTE:** The following [issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22628) mentions the same error but it appears that the problem was coming from using `GIT TAG` instead of `GIT_TAG`, which is not my case.

---

**UPDATE:**

The issue is in the syntax. Based on the CMake issue I've linked at the end of my post I started editing my `FetchContent_Declare()` call.

First I removed the whole section that is supposed to be passed down to the internal `ExternalProject_Add()` call (`CMAKE_ARGS`, `TMP_DIR` etc.). This was to ensure that I get the "pure" call. I still got the same error.

Next I commented out `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGES` but it didn't work.

Third I commented out the `SOURCE_DIR` and `SUBBUILD_DIR` so the only thing I got was the `GIT_REPOSITORY` and `GIT_TAG`. And it worked.

I started adding things back - all but `FIND_PACKAGE_ARGES` (which I actually don't need anyway :D), `SOURCE_DIR` and `SUBBUILD_DIR`. It worked as long as I put all `CMAKE_ARGS` on the same line (I thought this was supported since many CMake functions do but then again here we are passing a single value to a variable/option).

Apparently the error message is thrown for incorrect option (also some internal call doesn't like it) or incorrect value. However I still don't understand why the `SOURCE_DIR` and `SUBBUILD_DIR` are not working.

Comment: The documentation appears to be [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html). It's not immediately obvious to me how this relates to any arguments passed to `--work-tree` in Git, or whether there's any *direct* connection in the first place, but that's probably what's going on. See in particular the mentions of <lowercaseName>_SOURCE_DIR.